# How to send Large JSON Data to server using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I had created service that retrieves contacts from android device name, mobile number and email and stores in array list with custom object of contacts. I am having 20,000 contacts in my device. I am converting that array list to JSON Array using Gson. And I am sending data to server but request fails. If I am sending small amount of data then API gives successful response. I want to know why I am not able to have success request when there is large data in JSON format.
This is sample format data that i will send to server

```
[
 {
   "Name": "FirstName Lastname",
   "Phone": "[+123456789012]"
 },
 {
   "Name": "FirstName Lastname",
   "Phone": "[+123456789012, +123456789012, +123456789012]",
   "Email": "abcd@gmail.com"
 },
 {
   "Name": "FirstName Lastname",
   "Phone": "[+123456789012]"
 },
  {
   "Name": "FirstName Lastname",
   "Phone": "[]"
 }
]
```

This is print stack trace that I am getting

```
06-25 17:32:21.816 19421-20008/ D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x40d92618: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
06-25 17:32:21.826 19421-19421/ W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x40d92618: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
06-25 17:32:21.856 19421-19421/ W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_write(Native Method)
        at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:719)
        at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:79)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:180)
        at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:179)
        at okio.RealBufferedSink.writeUtf8(RealBufferedSink.java:54)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.writeRequest(Http1Codec.java:172)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.writeRequestHeaders(Http1Codec.java:130)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:50)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
```

Here is my service code that does all stuffs.

```
public class ContactService extends Service {

  String strDate;

  @Nullable
  CompositeDisposable mDisposable = null;
  private UploadContactsUseCase mUploadContactsUseCase;

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    //to convert Date to String, use format method of SimpleDateFormat class.
    strDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    new GetContacts().execute();
    stopSelf();
    // I don't want this service to stay in memory, so I stop it
    // immediately after doing what I wanted it to do.
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    if (mDisposable != null) {
      mDisposable.dispose();
      mDisposable = null;
    }
    // I want to restart this service again.
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1),
        PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, ContactService.class), 0));
  }

  private JSONArray displayContacts() {
    int j = 1;
    List<ContactUser> contactUserList = new ArrayList<ContactUser>();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur != null && cur.getCount() > 0) {
      while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        Log.i("COUNT: ", String.valueOf(j++));
        List<String> listPhones = new ArrayList<String>();
        ContactUser contactUser = new ContactUser();
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        contactUser.setName(name);
        if (Integer
            .parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)))
            > 0) {
          Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

          while (pCur != null && pCur.moveToNext()) {
            String phoneNo = pCur
                .getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
//            Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            Log.i("Contact", name + " " + ":" + " " + phoneNo);
            listPhones.add(phoneNo);
//            mStoreContacts.add(name + " " + ":" + " " + phoneNo);
          }
          if (pCur != null) {
            pCur.close();
          }
        }

        // get the user's email address
        String email = null;
        Cursor ce = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
        if (ce != null && ce.moveToFirst()) {
          email = ce.getString(ce.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
//          mStoreContacts.add(name + " " + ":" + " " + email);
          ce.close();
        }
        String[] array = listPhones.toArray(new String[0]);
        contactUser.setPhone(Arrays.toString(array));
        contactUser.setEmail(email);
        contactUserList.add(contactUser);
      }

      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
      for (int i = 0; i < contactUserList.size(); i++) {
        jsonArray.put(contactUserList.get(i).getJSONObject());
      }
      if (cur != null) {
        cur.close();
      }
      return jsonArray;
    }
    if (cur != null) {
      cur.close();
    }
    return null;
  }

  class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      Toast.makeText(ContactService.this, "Starting reading contacts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... voids) {
      JSONArray contacts = displayContacts();
      return contacts;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final JSONArray contact) {
      super.onPostExecute(contact);
//      new JobTask(contact).execute();
      try {
        Log.i("Contacts:", contact.toString(2));
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      mDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
      mUploadContactsUseCase = new UploadContactsUseCaseImpl();
      mDisposable.add(mUploadContactsUseCase
          .execute(Preferences.getInstance().getUserEmail(), contact.toString())
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(new Action() {
            @Override
            public void run() throws Exception {
              // handle completion
              Toast.makeText(ContactService.this, "Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
              throwable.printStackTrace();
              // handle error
              Toast.makeText(ContactService.this, throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                  .show();
            }
          }));
    }
  }
}
```

This is my network manager class of Retrofit

```
        public class NetworkManager {

  /**
   * The Constant CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_TIME.
   */
  private static final long CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_TIME = 30;

  private static final String CURRENT_LANG =
      Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().toString() + "-" + Locale.getDefault().getCountry();
  private static final String GZIP_DEFLATE = "gzip,deflate";
  /**
   * The Constant ACCEPT_ENCODING.
   */
  private static final String ACCEPT_ENCODING = "Accept-Encoding";
  /**
   * The Constant CONTENT_TYPE.
   */
  private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
  /**
   * The Constant APPLICATION_JSON.
   */
  private static final String APPLICATION_JSON = "application/json";
  private static final String BASE_URL = "https://mybaseurl.in";

  private static SafecodeApiService sInstanceV2 = null;
  private static SafecodeApiService sInstanceV2_1 = null;

  public static SafecodeApiService getService() {
    if (sInstanceV2 == null) {
      OkHttpClient client = getHttpClient();

      sInstanceV2 = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
          .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonFactory.create())).client(client)
          .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()).build()
          .create(SafecodeApiService.class);
    }
    return sInstanceV2;
  }

  @NonNull
  private static OkHttpClient getHttpClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder().followRedirects(true).followSslRedirects(true)
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(true).connectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS).cache(null)
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor).addInterceptor(new ResponseInterceptor()).build();
  }

  private static class ResponseInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
      try {
        Request original = chain.request();
        Request request = original.newBuilder().addHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
            .addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive").addHeader(ACCEPT_ENCODING, GZIP_DEFLATE)
            .method(original.method(), original.body()).build();

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        String rawJson = response.body().string();

        Log.i("RESPONSE: ", String.format("raw JSON response is: %s", rawJson));

        switch (response.code()) {
          case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
            // Re-create the response before returning it because body can be read only once
            return response.newBuilder()
                .body(ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), rawJson)).build();
          case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAVAILABLE:
            throw new MaintenanceException("Service Unavailable.");
          default:
            break;
        }
        return response;
      } catch (SocketTimeoutException exception) {
        throw new SocketTimeoutException("timeout");
      }
    }
  }

  private static class MaintenanceException extends RuntimeException {

    public MaintenanceException(String message) {
      super(message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of fail did you get in the request? Retrofit fail to post because of a timeout, or Gson fails to parse the large object. Anyway, using normal post request for large data is not ideal. Storing them in a file, have a sync service that manages sync process, post the file using Multipart post request, just like uploading image to a server is what I'll try.

Comment: @TamHuynh give me few mins I will post what error I am getting.

Comment: please post your code here and add logcat with error report please

Comment: @quicklearner I had posted my log please check it

Comment: please post the code also of your api request dear

Comment: @quicklearner I had added code please help me Thanks.

Comment: did you try adding retry timeout ?

Comment: @quicklearner please check my network manger class i had added. thanks

Comment: what is the value of CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_TIME ?

Comment: @quicklearner 30 seconds

Comment: Well change its value to 5 and do  .writeTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_TIME, TimeUnit.MINUTES) instead of seconds

Comment: @quicklearner tried as you told but not working

Comment: did you test it on postman with the same data ?

Comment: i think its from backend that issue , test it on postman

Comment: @quicklearner I am able to send max 50 contacts to server at a time. I had checked this practically on device. I am not able to send all 20000 contacts at same time. I changed my logic I will send one by one contact to server as and when retrieved from ContentResolver. I think this could be the only way and I think problem is with server that is not able to handle max character in post method of API. Thanks to all members who really helped me to resolve this issue.

Comment: yeah i knew its from backend , well try sending in packets like 10-50 at a time

Comment: @quicklearner thanks for helping out.

Comment: i am happy i could help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to send max 50 contacts to server at a time. I had checked this practically on device. I am not able to send all 20000 contacts at same time. I changed my logic I will send one by one contact to server as and when retrieved from ContentResolver. I think this could be the only way and I think problem is with server that is not able to handle max character in post method of API. Thanks to all members who really helped me to resolve this issue.